# Add custom phtml /block to regiration page magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi i want to add my custom phtml file or code to registration page using magento.I found the code for registration but dont know where i can update it.From customer.xml i got this code

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

My block code is

```
 <module_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/module" name="module" template="module/module.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </module_index_index>
```

I want to show my page at the end of registration page on my website.Thanks in adanace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a layout.xml file for your module.

First you will need to define this file in your module's config.xml:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_module>
                <file>your_module.xml</file>
            </your_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then create this layout file under: design/frontend/base/defualt/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/module" name="module" template="module/module.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

This should then add your module at the end of the registration page.

Comment: thanks for your response.I know this way but i want to inject my code to registration page when i want , and this can be happen by writing update xml for registration in my xml like (<update refrence >) not in core xml.Hope you got my point

Comment: This way will leave the core xml file un-edited and you simple have to create your own xml file with theses few lines. Your xml lines will just be added to the xml tree. Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry your answer is right.I have solved the problem with this code.Thanks again